# in tales of symphonia how do i open the black chests

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

In tales of symphonia for gamecube on the wii I have gotten the dark eye for Colette but abyssion was not in front of the hotel and the black scull and the black chest in the forest disappeared. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If during the story one of your characters is missing from the party, this sidequest doesn't continue until you get them back. Once you have all characters in your party again, go back to the hotel and find the man at Flanoir.

This info and more can be found in the [FAQ section here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps3/765388-tales-of-symphonia/faqs/32742).